# The usage of preposition 'around'

Tags: prepositions

A news reporter is giving some tips about how to tackle the spread of fake news.At the end, she gives her final tip and says" that sort of leads around to our top tips for stopping..."
Why does she use the preposition "around" ? Is "lead around' considered as a phrasal verb?

Comment: It's fine - arguably, ***around*** here is a slightly more "vague" usage than *...leads **on / up / in** to...* (but of course it's also fine without any "additional" preposition before ***to***).

Comment: I assume that "around" gives the idea of some circle of logic or continuity being completed.

Comment: (But I'd say the "phrasal verb" is still ***to lead to** = precede, cause, engender,...*, regardless of whether you include any of those additional "redundant" prepositions).

Comment: Media folk usually talk about ['segueing'](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/segue) one news item into another. Why did she not just say 'that segues neatly into our top tips' ?